# What to do about this window installation

Tags: windows, replacement, caulk, vinyl, leaking

Was investigating some leaky windows and wasn't expecting to see this configuration for replacement windows. These were done on the entire home 2 homeowners ago, now about 8 years old.

It looks like block frame windows are resting inside of the old aluminum frame. Flashing was installed and caulked to just the window and stucco or window and wood trim.

Is this a valid replacement method? I was expecting to see some kind of integral flange caulked/bonded to the old frame, not a separate piece of trim.

Recommendations on what to do if anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are two general categories of methods to replace windows.

1. One method involves tearing out the complete old window assembly back to the rough opening in the framing / sheathing. The window used for replacement would be one nominally designed for "new construction" installation. This method typically requires a lot of work to redo the outside siding, stucco, window trim (if any) and possibly the overhead flashing. On the inside it is often required to re-work the inside window trim framing and casing depending upon condition of the prior materials, dimensions of the new window and type of trim whether that be wood, drywall or other materials.
2. The second method is designed to allow the new window to be somehow fitted inside the old window frame / jamb. The types of windows used and the methods of attachment have everything to do with the style of the existing windows. Advantages are that the existing inside and outside trims and interfaces with the wall coverings are largely left undisturbed.

As you can imagine the first method is often way more expensive and time consuming. With careful planning and craftsmanship the first method usually ends up providing the superior result.

If the house is undergoing a major overhaul including exterior siding replacement then the first method usually is the approach used.